# How can I replace a line in a text file?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a text file:

```
123
456
789
```

I want to replace '456' with "AAA". How I can do that?

```
CStdioFile cfile;
CString line;
cfile.Open(_T("D\\text.txt"), CFile::modeReadWrite);
while (cfile.ReadString(line))
{
    if (line == L"456")
        cfile.WriteString(L"AAA");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works if the new and old line have the same length.

You can save the current position of the file stream. Seek back, to the old position, write the new line.

```
while (cfile.ReadString(line))
{ 
    auto llLine = cfile.GetPosition();
    if (line == L"456")
    {
       cfile.Seek(llLine, CFile::begin);
       cfile.WriteString(L"AAA");
    }
}
```

If the lines have a different length you need to write the contents into a new file and rename it after you made the changes.